# Invoked method from Python unit test issues

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I'm trying to invoke the following method, *post_sample* (filename index.py):

```
class Main(Resource):
    @app.route('/sample', methods=['POST'])
    def post_sample():
        return 'POST received'
```

From the following unittest code:

```
def test_post():
    Main().post_sample()
    print 'test_here'
```

But when I run I get the following error, which I'm having trouble making sense of:

```
>       Main().post_sample()
E       TypeError: post_sample() takes no arguments (1 given)

tests/test_post.py:8: TypeError
```

TIA!

Comment: why is there a class around your view function?

Comment: Are you using the [test client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/#the-first-test) for your unit-testing?

Comment: @wgwz Since I had a few functions I wrapped them in a class.

Comment: @idjaw No, I'm using py.test

Comment: @mr-sk Look in to that test client for Flask, it is very well done and will help with your unittests.

Comment: Did you try adding the `self` argument to the post_sample method?

Comment: No I fixed this by removing the class and leaving the methods as functions.

Answer (score 0):

`post_sample` is an instance method and as such must accept at minimum one argument, a reference to the instance:

```
def post_sample(self):
```